# How to get the ReleaseName (e.g Release-183) for my Azure functions to my Vuejs website

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have one backend repo and one frontend repo, i want to display on my website which Release the user currently is testing and so on.
It was pretty easy to get the frontend release to the UI using a File Transform Task and change a variable in a json file i have in the frontend project.

My plan for the backend was to do the same thing and then expose that variable with an API endpoint. But i didn't find any like "appsettings.json" file in my azure functions project in Azure to put my variable in, so my question now is, should i add a "custom" json file to my azure functions project and check that into my repo. Or is there a better/simpler way to achieve this?

I hope you understand what i want to achieve here!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the Azure DevOps Services REST API and the endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP
And this will solve my problem.